# how do you use libraries (dll/lib) in a cmake project using visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2

I have two libraries i am trying to use SDL2 and ReactPhysics3D. so far i am just trying to get SDL2 source to compile in a sub directory of my project and use it in a simple c++ program but i am getting a linking error.

my file structure is

```
-SDLReactGame
    -SDL2-2.0.12(source downloaded from libsdl.org)
    -ReactPhysics3D(source downloaded from reactphysics3d.com)
    -src
        -Game.cpp
    -CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt contents are as follows

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)

set(PROJECT_NAME SDLReactGame)
set(PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set(PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR 0)
set(PROJECT_VERSION "${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}")

# set the project name and version
project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)


# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory (SDL2-2.0.12)
#add_subdirectory (reactphysics3d-0.7.1)



# add the executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/Game.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "SDL2")
```

I believe i am missing this somewhere and i have tried it in a few different ways with not much luck. it seems like the include folder from the sdl project is not making it into the out folder when it gets built.

```
target_include_directories
```

this is my Game.cpp if i comment out all but the return 0; and just include SDL.h i get the error. also i have compiled this without cmake and got it to run. I was hoping that I could have the libraries in the same

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "SDL2Test",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        640,
        480,
        0
    );

    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();*/

    return 0;
}
```

Error Messages:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  ..\out\build\x64-Debug\SDLReactGame ..\out\build\x64-Debug\SDLReactGame.exe

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)    ..\out\build\x64-Debug\SDLReactGame ..\out\build\x64-Debug\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)

Comment: So, what is the error? Can you please put the **complete** error message in your question post?

Comment: these are the only error messages i get. i hope they help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out. building the sdl2 source code with cmake in visual studio produces 3 things SDL2 (shared Library) SDL2main (static library) and SDL2-static (static library).

i was using this

```
target_link_libraries(SDLReactGame "SDL2")
```

which from my understanding is what builds the dll file and i should have been using this

```
target_link_libraries(SDLReactGame "SDL2-static" "SDL2main")
```

which links to the two static libraries and gets rid of my lnk errors.

im guessing you dont link to dll files, but maybe need them in the binary folder where you build your project